# Firebase Authentication Emulator: "Do not allow login the email" Error in `authenticator.ts`

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to run a project with Firebase authentication and database Emulator. The project has authentication feature with email and password. But when I tried to sign up with a fake email address an error is raised on console.

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Do not allow login the email
    at FirebaseAuthenticator.<anonymous> (authenticator.ts:53:13)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (index.tsx:132:3)
```

I check `authenticator.ts` and seems like the emulator regards the email address invalid in some way. Now I can't find such a case in the official firebase document.

```
# authenticator.ts

async signUp(name: string, email: string, password: string): Promise<UserId> {
    await this.checkToAllowSigningUserWith(email);

    try {
      const auth = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.auth, email, password);
      const uid = auth.user.uid;

      const userId = createUserId(uid);
      const user = createUser({ id: userId, name, joinedGames: [] });
      this.userRepository.save(user);

      return userId;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
      throw e;
    }
  }

  private async checkToAllowSigningUserWith(email: string) {
    const definedUser = await get(ref(this.database, "defined-users"));
    const mails = (definedUser.val() as string[] | null) || [];
    const existsMail = mails.some((v) => v === email);

    if (!existsMail) {
      throw new Error("Do not allow login the email");
    }
  }
```

What is this function for and when it throws the error?

Comment: you have to enable it in `Auth -> Methods` in firebase console

Comment: Tried it on firebase console but still same error. Similar setting is on firebase emulator?